# Elasticsearch: find all docs with a specified date format?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index(only one doc_type) with a field of "date", mapping is below.

```
"date" : {
    "format" : "dateOptionalTime",
    "type" : "date"
}
```

when I scan the index, some doc looks like

```
"date": 1435820913000
```

while others looks like

```
"date": "2015-07-23T07:02:03"
```

so I want to know if there is some way to query all the doc with the "date" looks like 1435820913000(looks like a long).

Well, I decide to write a script(@Andrei Stefan), though script run rather slow, and I have to split this work into many parts by cdate(another date field in my docs) .  I have to use "_source" instead of "doc", "_source" is in my disk, which make this script run rather slow.

```
 {
     "query": {
         "filtered": {
             "query": {
                 "range": {
                     "cdate": {
                         "lte": "2015-07-04T00:00:00",
                         "gt": "2015-07-03T23:00:00"
                     }
                 }
             },
             "filter": {
                 "script": {
                     "script": "_source['date'] instanceof Long"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do at search time only. Is re-indexing possible?

Comment: No, the index is quite large,  has billions of docs. I want to know the number of dirty docs, and decide next.

Comment: Or maybe you can do it, but would not be any better than doing it yourself in a programming language. With ES you'd do it in Groovy scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use a script.